# Low level printf

Tags: c, pointers, assembly

I am trying to write my own printf with simple facilities.

Here is a code of printf.c:

```
#include "printf.h"

uint8 pos_x=0, pos_y=0;

void printf(char str[]){
    int i=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0'){
        switch(str[i]){
            case '\t':{
                uint8 k=0;
                while(k<TAB_WIDTH){
                    putCh(' ');
                    ++k;
                }
            }
            case '\n':newLn();
            default:putCh(str[i]);
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

void putCh(char ch){
    char *p=(char*)(VIDEO_MEM+2*(RES_X*pos_y + pos_x));
    asm(" xchg %bx, %bx");
    *p++=ch;
    *p++=ATTRIBUTE;
    ++pos_x;
}

void newLn(){
    pos_x=0;
    ++pos_y;
}
```

So, if I use the code above nothing works, but if I use this `*((int*)0xb8000)=0x07690748;` it works fine.

So, what are the problems with my pointers? Thanks!

P.S. All defines are in `printf.h`; function called form main like this:

```
char str[]="Hello!\n";
printf(str);
```

Edit1: Environment:

```
gcc 4.8.2 built for i586
Bochs 2.6.2
No OS
```

Edit2: printf.h

```
#ifndef _PRINF_F_
#define _PRINT_F_
#include "types.h"

#define VIDEO_MEM 0xb8000
#define RES_X 80
#define RES_Y 25
#define ATTRIBUTE 0x7
#define TAB_WIDTH 4

void printf(char[]);
void putCh(char);
void newLn();

#endif
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? And for a start this is not valid C `char str[]='Hello!';`

Comment: For one thing, your question is totally OS, compiler and compilation model-dependent, so it's impossible to answer without knowing your environment.  A key example is that the `xchg` instruction is a total mystery without knowing how your compiler stores parameters and values. For another thing your `switch` statement is missing `break`s, so the `\n` case is executing whenever the `\t` does.

Comment: Need to show `VIDEO_MEM` definition.  With `*((int*)0xb8000)=0x07690748;`, do you see "Hi"?

Comment: `*((int*)0xb8000)=0x07690748;` - I see `Hi`, I used this "command" to check possibility of writing to video memory

Comment: So 1+ of the following is wrong 1) VIDEO_MEM 2) RES_X 3) `asm(" xchg %bx, %bx")` not needed 4) ATTRIBUTE.  Show definition of the 3 macros.

Comment: what is the sizeof(int), 2, 4, or ?  Concern `VIDEO_MEM+2*(RES_X*pos_y + pos_x)` evaluates to only 2 bytes width.

Comment: I am emulating 32-bit core, so I think that `int` is 4 bytes size. P.S. I have no OS, so I don't know how to check it quickly

Comment: Yeah, likely size 4 if `*((int*)0xb8000)=0x07690748;` makes "Hi".  Please expand on "nothing works" and why `asm(" xchg %bx, %bx");`.  Maybe that should be before `char *p= ...`?  (or omitted)

Comment: Ok, "noting works" means that I have "Booting..." string printed in `Real mode`, if I use `*((int*)...` it becomes "Hioting..." string, and remained "Booting..." if I use my `printf` code. `asm(" xchg %bx, %bx");` is used for `magic breakpoint` in Bochs.

Comment: Can't see the problem cause.  GTG so some parting ideas: 1) `printf()` is OK, but "Hello! string is being magically changed to  "Booting..." - debug that.  2) use a different name than `printf()`, too easy to collide with the std lib function should it be lurking somewhere.  3) perform the video memory write as a uint16_t rather than 2 `char`.  `uint16_t *p = VIDEO_MEM; p[RES_X*pos_y + pos_x] = ch;`

Answer (score 1):

look up the syntax of a switch statement - specifically BREAK

Comment: Ah - the forest and not the trees.

Comment: I don't think that problem in `switch`, cause I test this "algo" with simple `while()` in `main` function, result was the same.

Comment: @Vanzef: You *DO* realize that all your cases are fall through, right?

Answer (score 0):

`pos_x` and `pos_y` are declared as `uint8`; consequently, `VIDEO_MEM+2*(RES_X*pos_y + pos_x)` is cast to `uint8` too. This happens *before* the result is cast to `char *`. Bits 8 and higher are cleared; VIDEO_MEM is totally cleared out.

This may help:

```
char *p = (char*)(VIDEO_MEM + 2 * (RES_X * (uint32)pos_y + pos_x));
```

That, plus the issues pointed out by the other contributors here.